# How to do Custom Order in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is my column

```
1-1
1-2
2-1
2-4
```

Is It possible to sort in this way - First Column should be be ascending and Second column should be descending

So the result will be

```
1-4
1-2
2-1
2-1
```

I don't care if the row mismatch. How can I achieve this (Something like view)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pipo_orders` (
      `ClientID` int(8) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT ,
    );

--
-- Dumping data for table `pipo_orders`
--

INSERT INTO `pipo_orders` (`ClientID`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(17, '2014-11-26 16:21:36', '2014-11-26 10:51:36'),
(17, '2014-11-26 16:46:24', '2014-11-26 11:16:24'),
(17, '2014-12-04 16:45:28', '2014-12-04 11:15:28'),
(17, '2014-12-26 12:58:13', '2014-12-26 07:28:13'),
(17, '2014-12-30 14:29:31', '2014-12-30 08:59:31'),
(17, '2014-12-30 14:31:05', '2014-12-30 09:01:05'),
(17, '2015-01-02 12:20:54', '2015-01-02 06:50:54');
```

Comment: thats ok. i just want to make sort or check the below table

Comment: This is not what databases are made for to sort related data unrelated. But when you really watn to do so you may create temporary tables reading  the auto_increment, create_at and clientId in first tmp table asc and auto_increment, updated_at and clientId in second table desc and the do a select with a join on the auto_increment. That will help you to destroy the logic of the related database table

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want it's weird, and I can't think of a reason why you'd want it. In fact, it goes against the fundamental logic of a database...
Nevertheless:

```
SELECT       t1.ClientID
,            t1.created_at
,            t2.updated_at
FROM         pipo_orders t1
JOIN         pipo_orders t2
       ON    1 = 1
ORDER BY     t1.created_at ASC
,            t2.update_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a horrible thing to do. The values created_at and updated_at are related by being in the same row. You override this relation and join completely unrelated values.

However to technically do this, you would have to order the two columns separately (giving them row numbers) and then join them again:

```
select
  col1.created_at,
  col2.updated_at
from
(
  select created_at, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 as rownum 
  from pipo_orders po
  cross join (select @rn1 := 0) as r
  order by created_at
) as col1
from
(
  select updated_at, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as rownum 
  from pipo_orders po
  cross join (select @rn2 := 0) as r
  order by updated_at desc
) as col2 using (rownum)
order by rownum;
```